# Managed Metadata column in power query

Tags: list, managed-metadata, powerview

Unable to load Managed Metadata column of a SharePoint list upon using PowerQuery.

Answer (score 1):

PowerQuery uses REST endpoints (listdata.svc) which unfortunately doesn't support Managed Metadata.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bba6f165-b012-4c5b-8e1b-a6e0093bb333/sharepoint-2013-managed-metadata-field-support?forum=lightswitch

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68f1418a-8a5b-4f7e-a575-3aaf532992aa/no-managed-metadata-columns-in-power-query-sharepoint-list-queries?forum=powerquery